# Real convergent sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$ be a bounded sequence for all $n$ such that $ \displaystyle a_n \geq \frac{1}{2} (a_{n-1}+a_{n+1})$ for $n\geq 2$. Show that $(a_n)$ converges.

I think I cannot use any convergence tests here. If I can show that $(a_n)$ is increasing or decreasing then I will win. But stucked in proving so. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: a nice way of rewriting the given inequality is 
$$
a_n-a_{n-1}\ge a_{n+1}-a_n
$$
So, letting $b_n=a_{n+1}-a_n$, the sequence $b_n$ is decreasing. So, if some $b_n=-\epsilon<0$, then all subsequent $b_{n+k}$ are beneath $-\epsilon$ as well. What would this imply in terms of the original sequence $a_n$?

Comment: It implies that $(a_n)$ decreasing. But how do we know that $b_n<0$ for some $n$?

Comment: Ok, if $b_n$ is not less than $0$ for some $n$ then that means $b_n\geq 0$ for all $n$. Then $(a_n)$ increasing. So in each case $(a_n)$ converges. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that works1 You can actually show the case where some $b_n<0$ leads to a contradiction, since if $b_n=-\epsilon$, then every $b_{n+k}\ge -\epsilon$, so that the difference $$a_{n+k}-a_n=b_n+b_{n+1}+\dots+b_{n+k-1}$$ grows without bound, implying $a_n$ is unbounded.

Comment: $b_{n+k}\geq -\epsilon$ ? How?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say $b_{n+k}\le-\epsilon$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But when $b_n<0$ it does not lead to a contradiction. Because since $(a_n)$ bounded $(b_n)$ also bounded and in this case we get $(a_n)$ decreasing. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The condition implies $a_{n+1} \leq 2a_n-a_{n-1}$. A rearrangement gives:

$a_{n+1}-a_n \leq a_n-a_{n-1}$. So, the sequence $\{a_{n+1}-a_n\}$ is decreasing, and is bounded as $a_n$ is bounded. Hence this sequence converges.

It's a well known fact that if a sequence converges, then the Cesaro means of the sequence converge as well, and to the same value.

The $N$-th Cesaro mean of $\{a_{n+1}-a_n\}$ is $\dfrac{1}{N}(a_{N+1}-a_1)$ which converges to $0$ as $\{a_n\}$ is bounded.

Now, similar trick would give you that $\{a_{n+m}-a_n\}$ converges to $0$ for $m$ fixed. Thus the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is Cauchy, and hence it converges.